# How to get rid of link error in FreeGLUT MS Visual Studio project build with Cmake + Conan?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, conan

Im trying build freeGLUT project with cmake and conan for MS Visual Studio, but when I build it return link error LNK1104 "Cant open file "freeglut.lib" for Release and "Cant open file "freeglutd.lib" for Debug.

Visual Studio 16 2019

Cmake 3.20.3

Conan 1.39.0

[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urU9H.png)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(OpenGLConan)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)

add_subdirectory(src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(FreeGLUT)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${FreeGLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${FreeGLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

**conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
freeglut/3.2.1

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

**src/main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    /* Create a single window with a keyboard and display callback */
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");

    /* Run the GLUT event loop */
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit**

In CMakeLists.txt I added

```
...
if(${FreeGLUT_FOUND})
    message(STATUS "-----LIB FOUND!!!-----")
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${FreeGLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${FreeGLUT_LIBRARIES})
endif()
...
```

Information from the console.

```
$ conan install ..
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64     
build_type=Release    
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.runtime=MD   
compiler.version=16   
os=Windows
os_build=Windows      
[options]
[build_requires]      
[env]

conanfile.txt: Installing package
Requirements
    freeglut/3.2.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
    glu/system from 'conancenter' - Cache
    opengl/system from 'conancenter' - Cache
Packages
    freeglut/3.2.1:d72ca9d65490ffa06c751d72974c9906d3454d5c - Cache
    glu/system:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache    
    opengl/system:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache 

Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
opengl/system: Already installed!
glu/system: Already installed!
freeglut/3.2.1: Already installed!
conanfile.txt: Generator cmake_paths created conan_paths.cmake
conanfile.txt: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generator cmake_find_package created FindFreeGLUT.cmake
conanfile.txt: Generator cmake_find_package created Findglu.cmake
conanfile.txt: Generator cmake_find_package created Findopengl_system.cmake
conanfile.txt: Aggregating env generators
conanfile.txt: Generated conaninfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generated graphinfo

Антон@LAPTOP-4L8RSG2A MINGW64 /d/GitHub/OpenGLConan/build
$ cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: Using autogenerated FindFreeGLUT.cmake
-- Found FreeGLUT: 3.2.1 (found version "3.2.1") 
-- Library glut found C:/Users/Anton/.conan/data/freeglut/3.2.1/_/_/package/d72ca9d65490ffa06c751d72974c9906d3454d5c/lib/glut.lib
-- Found: C:/Users/Anton/.conan/data/freeglut/3.2.1/_/_/package/d72ca9d65490ffa06c751d72974c9906d3454d5c/lib/glut.lib
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findopengl_system.cmake
-- Found opengl_system: system (found version "system") 
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findglu.cmake
-- Found glu: system (found version "system")
-- Dependency opengl_system already found
-- Library glut found C:/Users/Anton/.conan/data/freeglut/3.2.1/_/_/package/d72ca9d65490ffa06c751d72974c9906d3454d5c/lib/glut.lib
-- Found: C:/Users/Anton/.conan/data/freeglut/3.2.1/_/_/package/d72ca9d65490ffa06c751d72974c9906d3454d5c/lib/glut.lib
-- -----LIB FOUND!!!-----
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/GitHub/OpenGLConan/build

Антон@LAPTOP-4L8RSG2A MINGW64 /d/GitHub/OpenGLConan/build
$ cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 16.10.2+857e5a733 для .NET Framework
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/GitHub/OpenGLConan/src/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "freeglutd.lib" [D:\GitHub\OpenGLConan\build\src\OpenGLConan.vcxproj]
```

Comment: ```Cant open file "freeglut.lib"``` probably means it is incompatible with cmake, or whatever compiler are you using and get this error. Maybe it means it can't find the file, you should check. Try to move file to different location and see if error is still the same. If it is not the same, it means binary incompatibility with your compiler. If it is the same, check your library paths.

Comment: Are you sure that `FreeGLUT` package has been found? (You could either check the output of configuration process, or use REQUIRED keyword: `find_package(FreeGLUT REQUIRED)`). Not sure about Conan, but in other cases `find_package` is called for `GLUT`, not for `FreeGLUT`. E.g. CMake provides [FindGLUT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLUT.html) module.

Comment: You need to be sure about your profile, by default, Conan will install Release, Runtime MD and Static library. Also, check the Cmake output, when finding a library, it lists the library path. Please, share more details, as you entire CMake log.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Conan generator `cmake_find_package` creates `FindFreeGLUT.cmake` file, so that module name is correct. You can check on the [upstream](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/freeglut/all/conanfile.py#L108). I suspect just like you, Cmake didn't find that library.

Comment: @uilianries I added information from console to post and libraries it finds

Comment: As I explained before, Conan, by default, installs Release build type. In your command line, you executed `cmake ..` with no build type declared, so cmake is configured to Debug. Thus, you are mixing Release and Debug. Usually it is not a problem, but for FreeGLUT, the library name changes according the build type. So, you must pass -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release when configuring cmake

Comment: To be more precise, in your error message, `freeglutd.lib` is expected, there is a `d` as suffix for Debug. But your FreeGLUT conan package installed is Release build type and there is no suffix. Indeed cmake found FreeGLUT folder and libs, but they are a pattern (FreeGLUT_LIBRARIES), not because the expected name is correct or not.
If you want to build on Debug mode, you must pass the build type to Conan when installing: `conan install .. -s build_type=Debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is in the conanfile of freeglut. Conan file be default says in packaging:

```
self.cpp_info.components["freeglut_"].names["pkg_config"] = "freeglut" if self.settings.os == "Windows" else "glut"
```

So it tries to find `freeglut`.

At the same time be default conanfile sets `"replace_glut": True`. From Cmake this option sets:

```
option to build either as "glut" (ON) or "freeglut" (OFF)
```

So your library is built as `glut`, but conanfile still tries to find `freeglut`.
I would suggest you try to build conan package with option `replace_glut=False`

If that fixes the issue, pls open a bug here: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues

Comment: No, components names are equivalent to cmake targets, and they are correct. The file name expected is FreeGLUT, as listed at line [108](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/freeglut/all/conanfile.py#L108). That error is a misconfiguration between build types. Cmake wants Debug, but Conan installed Release.

Comment: @uilianries I did try your suggestion with the example above and it still shows same error.